# in mechanize, is there anyway of rewriting the url to POST to in a form?

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm running a python script and I'm using mechanize. The form i'm trying to submit normally uses javascript to rewrite the url to POST to, so to correctly submit the form i need to manually do the same. is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize doesn't process Javascript. The best way usually is to use browser to process Javascript - if you prefer do it in Python use [PythonExt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7620/).

Also you can try Selenium - seleniumhq.org. It's used for web-site testing but can send forms too.

Answer (score 1):

you may test zope http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=zope.testbrowser